# removing local git repositary from Xcode Project?

Tags: xcode, git, xcode4.2, git-svn

I had selected local git repositary when I created xcode Project.
But when import to SVN and commit, it commits locally not in SVN.
How can I resolve this problem? I want to remove all hidden local git files from the Xcode project without affecting source code? any help please?

Answer (score 16):

Open Terminal and Type

```
defaults write com.apple.finder AppleShowAllFiles TRUE
killall Finder
```

open the project in finder 
**delete** the .git

Good to go. Enjoy

Comment: no need the Terminal. just cmd+shift+. in Finder

Answer (score 4):

Open the folder the project is in, hold down Cmd, Shift, . (period) and you will see a folder named ".git". Delete that folder, and you're good. Hide hidden files again by holding down Cmd, Shift, . (period)

Answer (score 2):

The local git repository is stored in a folder named `.git` inside your project folder. It's hidden (any file/folder starting with a `.` is) but you can delete or move it using the Terminal. Once it's gone, your folder will no longer be recognized as having a git repository.